# How to refactor this code to remove output variable?

Tags: ruby, refactoring

```
def peel array
  output = []

  while ! array.empty? do
    output << array.shift
    mutate! array
  end

  output.flatten
end
```

I have not included the mutate! method, because I am only interested in removing the output variable. The mutate! call is important because we cannot iterate over the array using each because array is changing.

EDIT: I am getting an array as output, which is what I want. The method works correctly, but I think there is a way to collect the `array.shift` values without using a temp variable.

EDIT #2: OK, here is the mutate! method and test case:

```
def mutate! array
  array.reverse!
end

a = (1..5).to_a
peel( a ).should == [ 1, 5, 2, 4, 3 ]
```

It doesn't matter if `peel` modifies array. I guess it should be called `peel!`. Yes, `mutate!` must be called after each element is removed.

Comment: what are you getting as output at the moment, and what do you want to get?

Comment: @dax means that it would be helpful if you could include some example input and the expected corresponding output so we can see how to simplify your code without breaking functionality. Complete code which actually executes (a minimal example) also helps us help you.

Comment: There are too many details missing to be able to give a worthwhile answer. Is it important that the original array is modified by the `peel` method, or is that just an unintended side effect of using `shift`? Is it important that `mutate!` is called after each element is added? What does it do?

Comment: Is it really worth destroying the readability of your code to refactor out one lousy, short lived local variable? You wont gain any performance.

Comment: @Linuxios - It's not for performance. I think it would be more idiomatic. It's also more declarative.

Comment: @Linuxios - I think it's an interesting problem, not because @B would adopt any of the answers, but just as a mental exercise. I've spent a little time over at SE's [code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions), where the objective is normally to write a program that will complete a given task, using as few characters as possible.  I've actually sharpened my Ruby skills quite a bit working on some of those problems.

Comment: If you were content to use a temporary variable to hold a single element of the array, you could employ a sequence of `insert` and `delete_at`, but that does not work on the array directly (without the temporary variable).

Answer (score 1):

All this reversing makes me dizzy.

```
def peel(array)
  indices = array.size.times.map do |i|
    i = -i if i.odd?
    i = i/2
  end 
  array.values_at(*indices) # indices will be [0, -1, 1, -2, 2] in the example
end

a = (1..5).to_a
p peel(a) #=>[1, 5, 2, 4, 3]
```

Comment: I thought the objective was to avoid the use of temporary variables, such as `output` in the question or `indices` here.

Comment: @Cary Ah yes. The first version was something like `array.size.times.map{|i| i=-i if i.odd?; i = i/2; array[i]}` but I guessed `values_at` would perform better, forgetting about the original question.

Comment: `array.size.times` can be written as `array.each_index`. I personally find that a bit easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
def peel(array)
  mid = array.size/2
  array[0..mid]
    .zip(array[mid..-1].reverse)
    .flatten(1)
    .take(array.size)
end
```

Usage:

```
peel [1,2,3,4,5,6]
#=> [1, 6, 2, 5, 3, 4]

peel [1,2,3,4,5]
#=> [1, 5, 2, 4, 3]
```

Comment: No need for comment-clutter.  I suggest you delete yours, then when I see you have done so, I'll delete this one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using parallel assignment:

```
def peel array
  n = array.size
  n.times {|i| (n-2-2*i).times {|j| array[n-1-j], array[n-2-j] = array[n-2-j], array[n-1-j]}}
  array      
end

peel [1,2,3,4,5] # => [1,5,2,4,3]
peel [1,2,3,4,5,6] # => [1,6,2,5,3,4]
```

What I'm doing here is a series of pairwise exchanges.  By way of example, for `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`, the first 6-2=4 steps (6 being the size of the array) alter the array as follows:

```
[1,2,3,4,6,5]
[1,2,3,6,4,5]
[1,2,6,3,4,5]
[1,6,2,3,4,5]
```

The 1, 6 and the 2 are in now the right positions.  We repeat these steps, but this time only 6-4=2 times, to move the 5 and 3 into the correct positions:

```
[1,6,2,3,5,4]
[1,6,2,5,3,4]
```

The 4 is pushed to the end, it's correct position, so we are finished.